# Tuleap Subversion 404 page loading issue

Tags: svn, tuleap

After creating a new project in Tuleap

In Subversion tab, when I click Browse SVN Tree tab, it displays following error message:

> An Exception Has Occured
>
> The root "shortname" is unknown. If you believe the value is correct, then please double-check your configuration
>
> HTTP Response Status
>
> 404 Repository not found.

Where do I need to check my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You shall activate the backend: "service tuleap start" (as root) and wait for the queue to be purged (you can check as site admin in system event monitoring page)